# Can you use the data explorer to view an offline (local) data dump?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

Was just looking into the possibility of having an offline local copy of stack overflow for when I'm internetless.  I found a [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/stack-exchange-data-explorer-2-0/#comments) about the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), although it looks like it's designed to be used online.  The [source code](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/) for the data explorer is available, and I'm guessing that would make it possible to download and modify to point at an offline dump.  Has anyone tried this, or found a better approach?

Comment: **It's Batman!**  *goes to warn the Joker, who obviously hangs out on MSO*

Comment: Define what you mean by "offline dump"...You can load the data dumps into a local SQL Server instance and run Data Explorer off of that, of course.

Comment: Wouldn't a better approach be to just query your database directly with SSMS (assuming you're using SQL Server). I love DATA.SE but its not as good as SSMS

Comment: Tim, [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sep-11/) is what I meant by offline dump, which seems to be what you assumed. Thanks for the tip, do you have a link for further reading on loading data dumps into SQL Server?

Comment: Conrad, thanks for the tip, I'll look into it.  TO THE BATCAVE!

Comment: I'm sure you can find a tool on your belt for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, nothing is stopping you loading up the data dump using a tool like [SODDI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44330/do-you-want-to-quickly-and-easily-import-the-so-data-dump-into-your-sql-server) and running it locally on a windows box. I do so myself. There is some basic doco in the [readme](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/Readme.txt).

Comment: This looks to be what I was looking to do.  Thanks for the tip, I'll give it a try some time today and confirm your answer.